# How to make a canvas text that automatically updates the results in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make a dice rolling simulator and I want the result as a txt to show in the red box.
i created a canvas to create a rectangle box and on the canvas I created a txt line where the result should go but I don't have any idea on how to make the result show in the canvax rectangle box.
I am a first-year IT and I am really struggling on how to do it.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import random


root = Tk()
root.geometry('700x700')
root.title('Dice Rolling Simulation')

bg = PhotoImage(file ="bg.png")
label = Label(root, image=bg)
label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth =1, relheight = 1)



l0 = Label(root, text="")
l0.pack()

l1 = Label(root, text="DICE SIMULATOR", fg="white",
               bg='#000009',
               font="Helvetica 30 bold italic")
l1.pack()

# images
dice = ['die1.png', 'die2.png', 'die3.png', 'die4.png', 'die5.png', 'die6.png']
image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(random.choice(dice)))
label1 =Label(root, image=image1)
label1.image = image1
label1.pack(expand=True)

count = 0
size = 26


def rolling_dice():
    image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(random.choice(dice)))
    # update image
    label1.configure(image=image1)
    # keep a reference
    label1.image = image1


def contract():
    global count, size
    if count <=10 and count > 0:
        size -=2
        my_button.config(font=("Helvetica", size))
        count -=1
        root.after(10, contract)

def expand():
    global count,size
    if count <10:
        size +=2
        my_button.config(font=("Helvetica", size))
        count +=1
        root.after(10, expand)

    elif count == 10:
        contract()

def exit():
    response=messagebox.askyesno('Exit','Are you sure you want to exit?')
    if response:
        root.destroy()

canvas= Canvas(root, width = 200, height = 50, bg = "red")
canvas.pack(pady = 5)
canvas.create_text(100, 25,fill="darkblue",font="Times 20 italic bold",
                        text= image1)

my_button = Button(root, text = "ROLL THE DICE", command = lambda : [expand(), rolling_dice()],
                   font = ("Helvetica",24), fg="blue")

my_button.pack(pady=20)

exit = Button(root, text = "Exit", command = exit,  font = ("Helvetica",24), fg="red")
exit.pack(pady=10)



root.mainloop()
```

[This is the actual image of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAt9S.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save a reference to the text item, and then use `itemconfigure` method to change the text:

```
text_item = canvas.create_text(100, 25,...)
...
canvas.itemconfigure(text_item, text="something")
```